# Right way to SkipTo not empty tokens with ZeroOrMore in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have some pseudocode `txt_block-[seq_block]-txt-block[seq_block][seq-block]`. I want extract all `txt` and `seq` block with storing sequence.

```
ZeroOrMore(nestedExpr('[', ']') | SkipTo(Literal('[')) | StringEnd()))
```

But parsing go to infinity loop because `SkipTo` always return empty string. Simplified example:

```
ZeroOrMore(SkipTo('p')).parseString('p')
```

Currently I inherite `SkipTo` and copypaste `parseImpl` method with empty checking:

```
if not skipText:
     raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
```

But it look ugly. What right way to process this pseudocode with pyparsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo illustrating your situation:

```
from pyparsing import *

parser = "A" + SkipTo("B") + "B"

for test in ("ABC", "AXBC"):
    try:
        print test
        print parser.parseString(test)
    except ParseException as pe:
        print "exception:", pe
    print
```

And this prints:

```
ABC
['A', '', 'B']

AXBC
['A', 'X', 'B']
```

The first match is something you don't want - you don't want the SkipTo to succeed if it is going to be empty.

To add some extra validation on any parser element, you can define a parse action and have that method raise a ParseException if the validation rules aren't met.  In your case, the matching tokens for the SkipTo element must not be empty.  Here is a parse action that checks this:

```
def mustNotBeEmpty(tokens):
    if not tokens[0]:
        raise ParseException("match must not be empty")

parser = "A" + SkipTo("B").setParseAction(mustNotBeEmpty) + "B"
```

Now, running the same test code as above gives:

```
ABC
exception: match must not be empty (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

AXBC
['A', 'X', 'B']
```